# Python sizers - vertical column in horizontal row?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm learning wxPython and I'm having an issue. Here is my code below. It doesn't really work. What I'm trying to do is get a button in the top left section below the text area that says "Enter Task". I want the text input area and "enter task" button to be in a column so that the combined height of the two equals the height of the Start and Exit buttons next to them. Any help? Sizers confuse me.

```
import wx
import datetime

class UpperPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)



        #Timer
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.Update, self.timer)     

        #Enter Task Field
        self.edit = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, size=wx.Size(200, -1))
        #Enter Task Button
        self.button = wx.Button(self, -1, label="Enter!")
        self.midpanel = MiddlePanel(self)
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.midpanel.OnEnterPressed)
        #Start/Stop Button
        self.start_button=wx.Button(self, label="Start", size=(150,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, MiddlePanel.StartButton, self.start_button)
        #Exit Button
        self.exit_button=wx.Button(self, -1, label="Exit", size=(150,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, MainWin.CloseButton, self.exit_button)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.edit, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.start_button, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.exit_button, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

#=====================================================================        

class MiddlePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

        #Initialize Variables
        self.box_height = 100
        self.box_count = 0
        self.start_time = ''



    def OnEnterPressed(self, event):
        #Get entered text
        uppanel = UpperPanel(self)
        self.box_label = uppanel.edit.GetValue()

        if self.box_count < 10:
            for x in range(0, 1):
                chbx1 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, self.box_label)
                txtbx1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1)
                self.box_height += 30
                uppanel.edit.Clear()
                print("CLEARED!")
                print self.box_count
                print uppanel.edit.GetValue()
                #self.Layout()
            self.box_count += 1

    def StartButton(self,event):
        self.start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        btn_label = self.start_button.GetLabel()

        if btn_label == "Start":
            print "starting timer..."
            self.timer.Start(1000)
            self.start_button.SetLabel("Stop")
        else:
            print "timer stopped!"
            self.timer.Stop()
            self.start_button.SetLabel("Start")
        print ('Start button pressed.')

    def Update(self, event):       
        seconds = (self.start_time - datetime.datetime.now() +
                   datetime.timedelta(days=1)).seconds
        self.time_text.SetLabel('Time till next task:\n%d hours %d \
minutes %d seconds'
                                % (seconds / 3600,
                                   (seconds / 60)
                                   % (seconds / 3600 * 60),
                                   seconds % 60))





#======================================================================
class MainWin(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)

        self.middlePanel = MiddlePanel(self)
        self.upperPanel = UpperPanel(self)
        self.textArea = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(-1, 300), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.upperPanel, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.middlePanel, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.textArea, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

        #Window Closer
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.CloseWindow)

        #Create Menu Bar
        status=self.CreateStatusBar()
        menubar=wx.MenuBar()
        firstmenu=wx.Menu()
        secondmenu=wx.Menu()
        firstmenu.Append(wx.NewId(),"Start","Starts the timer.")
        firstmenu.Append(wx.NewId(),"Stop","Stops the timer.")
        firstmenu.Append(wx.NewId(),"Exit","Exits the program.")
        secondmenu.Append(wx.NewId(),"Preferences","Set the timer options.")
        secondmenu.Append(wx.NewId(),"Edit task list",
                          "Add, change, or remove tasks.") 
        menubar.Append(firstmenu,"File")
        menubar.Append(secondmenu,"Edit")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)



        #Static Text
        self.st1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Enter Tasks:')
        self.st2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Created by Spencer Evans')
        self.time_text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, '')

    def CloseButton(self,event):
        #timer.Stop()
        self.Close(True)
        print ('Closed by Exit button.')

    def CloseWindow(self,event):
        #timer.Stop()
        self.Destroy()
        print ('Closed by X\'ing window.')

#========================================================================
#Run program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    main_win = MainWin()
    main_win.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know where your problem is. In my opinion all of the parts where already there, you just have to put them together. If I understood what you wanted, just replace the text field by a panel containing the text field and a button with a vertical sizer. Nice typing exercise, let me suggest a solution:

```
--- /tmp/test.py
+++ /tmp/test2.py
@@ -11,8 +11,19 @@
         self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
         self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.Update, self.timer)     

+        # Panel for 'Enter Task' textfield and button
+        enter_task_panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
+        task_panel_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
+        enter_task_panel.SetSizer(task_panel_sizer)
+
         #Enter Task Field
-        self.edit = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, size=wx.Size(200, -1))
+        self.edit = wx.TextCtrl(enter_task_panel, -1, size=wx.Size(200, -1))
+        task_panel_sizer.Add(self.edit, 1)
+
+        # 'Enter Task' button
+        enter_task_button = wx.Button(enter_task_panel, -1, "Enter Task")
+        task_panel_sizer.Add(enter_task_button, 1, wx.EXPAND)
+
         #Enter Task Button
         self.button = wx.Button(self, -1, label="Enter!")
         self.midpanel = MiddlePanel(self)
@@ -25,7 +36,7 @@
         self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, MainWin.CloseButton, self.exit_button)

          self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
-         self.sizer.Add(self.edit, 1, wx.EXPAND)
+         self.sizer.Add(enter_task_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
          self.sizer.Add(self.start_button, 0, wx.EXPAND)
          self.sizer.Add(self.exit_button, 0, wx.EXPAND)
```

[Zetcode](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/) has a pretty good tutorial on wxPython, I can only recommend.